# An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: Invalid metrics list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

i'm facing below issue while creating alarm by using put_metric_alarm function in Python

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm 
operation: Invalid metrics list
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/manage_alarms.py", line 672, in handle_alarms
manage_alarms(cluster_name, sns, sections, namespace, None, None, None,None)
File "/var/task/manage_alarms.py", line 584, in manage_alarms
create_alarm(alarm_name, metric_json, alarm_json,sns)
File "/var/task/manage_alarms.py", line 262, in create_alarm
response = client.put_metric_alarm(AlarmName=alarm_name,
AlarmDescription=alarm_json['Description'],
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

i'm sending the payload like below,

```
metric_stat_json = [{'Id': 'bytesdropcountblackhole_math', 'MetricStat': {'Metric': 
{'MetricName': 'bytesdropcountblackhole', 'Namespace': 'AWS/TransitGateway', 'Dimensions': 
[{'Name': 'TransitGateway', 'Value': 'tgw-09a7a181c16936efb'}]}, 'Period': 300, 'Stat': 
'Average', 'Unit': 'Count'}, 'ReturnData': False}, {'Id': 'bytesdropcountblackhole_expr', 
'Expression': 'DIFF(bytesdropcountblackhole_math)', 'ReturnData': True}]

response=client.put_metric_alarm(AlarmName=alarm_name, AlarmDescription=alarm_json['Description'],
                        ComparisonOperator=alarm_json['Comparison'], EvaluationPeriods=alarm_json['EvalPeriod'],AlarmActions=[sns],
                        InsufficientDataActions=[sns],OKActions=[sns],Threshold=set_val,Metrics=metric_stat_json,Tags=tags)
```

Comment: Please supply the full code snippet, and format the code as well, its horrible to read it like this. Also, what is `[sns]`?

Comment: Hey @NathanGetty Thanks for responding, BTW, i found the issue and fixed.. and the issue was with Uppercase in ID while creating alarm, as per AWS documentation, we should pass ID in lowercase letters while generating the alarms